# Setting a property of all objects of an Iterable

Tags: java

is there a smart way to set a property of all objects of an Iterable to a specified value?

I have a class SystemUser that looks like that:

```
class SystemUser{
  private String name;
  private String password;
  ...
}
```

and another class that generates an Iterable object like:

```
public Iterable<SystemUser> getUsers(){
   ...
   return users;
}
```

Can I set the attribute "password" of all objects of the Iterable to null without iterating?

Thanks!

Comment: An Iterable is meant to be iterated. How could you go through all element of an iterable without iterating?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting any password into a `String` in the first place. You should read a password into a `char[]`, immediately hash it, and then overwrite the `char[]` to erase any trace of the original password.

Comment: maybe op wants an inline way to iterate and set it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've already set the password before amalgamating them into that `Iterable`, their password (and name) is already set to `null` by virtue of the [initial value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for references.

If you have set the password for one or any number of them before their amalgamation, you would have to iterate, either through standard `for` statements or through the use of `forEach` and streams.

Answer (score 0):

Any way to apply any function to item You need to iterate over all element and change the value.There is lot of 3rd party library available for this purpose like 
GUAVA OR as suggested above foreach.

Util using generic

```
public static <T> void apply(Iterable<T> iterable, Function<T, Void> function) {
    for (T input : iterable)
        function.apply(input);
}
```

using guava

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("race", "box");
final List<String> transformed =
    Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String apply(final String input) {
            return new StringBuilder().append(input).append("car").toString();
        }
    }));
```

Using for-each

```
// Suppose that I have already init the list of car
List<Car> cars = //...
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

// LAMBDA EXPRESSION
cars.forEach( (car) -> names.add(car.getName()) );
```